# How to trigger?

Tags: jquery

I have a little piece of code I want to trigger when the windows gets to 640px. or below
I have tried many different suggestions, I have found here or elsewhere but none of them works.

```
$(function() {
    $('p').css('display','none');
        $('h1').click(function(){
            $('p').stop(true,true).slideToggle(1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Bind to the window `resize` event to run a function whenever the window size changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind window resize events by doing:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(event){
// Do stuff here
});
```

You can get the window size by doing:

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
if(windowWidth < 640){
    // Do stuff here
}
```

So, your function will work like this:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(event)
    {
       var windowWidth = $(window).width();
       if(windowWidth < 640){
       $('p').css('display','none');
           $('h1').click(function(){
               $('p').stop(true,true).slideToggle(1000);
       });

    }
});
```

Comment: `click` handler will get added multiple times as and when `window` gets below 640px. You need to take care of it so that it wont happen multiple time.

Comment: I didn't make the code error proof, I just show him the way. But there could be a boolean to check if the function were already trigged once.

Comment: I have just tested it and the problem is, like my own code, that it also works when the window id wider than 640px. I have also tried an if else-statement, but what ever I have tried it does not seem to work...